# How to use index and match with two columns?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have the following case[image]

E.g., I want the two cells in yellow to be the same. For this, I need to find the columns Score 1 and Result, and then find the row 03-Jan so that I get the actual score. Do you have any idea how to solve this? I tried with some match and index but I do not get the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use INDEX with three matches, the first to find the correct row, while the other 2 find the correct column.

```
=INDEX($E:$N,MATCH($Q9,B:B,0),MATCH(R$8,$E$2:$N$2,0)+MATCH(R$7,$E$3:$I$3,0)-1)
```

Answer (score -1):

You want to use an Index(Match),Match())

but what you really want to use is a double XLOOKUP.
[image]

I also liked this video to help me learn all of the ways to do a 2d lookup.
[YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8dwmvTka3gs)

Comment: Your data is different from the OP.  There are two criteria in the OP's question that define the correct column, not one.  And you are assuming with your INDEX/(X)MATCH/(X)MATCH that the data is sorted ascending both in the column and the row.  Which may work, but as the OP is looking for exact matches, such should be dictated.

Comment: Another note, OP tagged it for Excel 2010 which does not have XLOOKUP or XMATCH.